# Facebook like button not showing after installing new theme?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I added a like button extension,it is perfectly fine as it was showing in the default theme but it is not showing anymore after installing a new theme.
can anyone tell me the reason please..?

I am using magento 1.6.

Comment: you have to adapt your new theme for Fblike extension. It seems some part of functionality, that are used by fblike extension, was removed/not implemented for new theme

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the template files of your plugin to the directory of the new extension.

Move them from /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/ to /app/design/frontend/newtheme/default/template/ ...